# Retrieve only the column of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

After doing an Sql query, I have an array that looks like the one below.
I would like to retrieve only the "name" column in a way that the names are like this: "Name1, Name2, Name3".
I have no idea how to do this, I looked on the internet but I find nothing conclusive.
Do you have any idea how to retrieve all the data from the "name" column?
Thank you in advance.

```
Array =
[1] {
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom1'
},
[2] {
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom2'
},
[3]  {
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom3'
}
```

I forgot one information: the array comes from an SQL query **rows2[].name.**

Comment: `let result=array.map(data=>data.name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the `map` function on any JavaScript array, docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Basically a map function tranforms type "A" to type "B".
In your case you want to go from the type:

```
Array<{
    id_idx: number,
    hero_order: number,
    name: string
}>
```

To:

```
Array<string>
```

This can be done with the map function as follows:

```
const names = myArray.map(a => a.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should give you a working solution -

```js
const result = [{
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom1'
},
{
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom2'
},
{
    id_idx: 1,
    hero_order: 0,
    name: 'Nom3'
}]

const outputArray = result.map((singleResult) => singleResult.name);

const outputString = outputArray.join(",");

console.log("This will give you an array as output - " + outputArray);

console.log("This will give you string as a output - " + outputString);

console.log('outputArray type:' + typeof outputArray);

console.log('outputString type:' + typeof outputString);
```